# In OpenCV 3.4.8 how to pass an array of cv::KeyPoint object type from Python to OpenCV C++?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I am trying to pass a list of keypoints of datatype `cv::KeyPoint` from Python to OpenCV C++:

For context, an object of datatype `cv::KeyPoint` is composed of the following data and corresponding datatype from Python perspective:

- 'x', np.float32
- 'y', np.float32
- 'size', np.float32
- 'angle', np.float32
- 'response', np.float32
- 'octave', np.int32
- 'class_id', np.int32

Depending on the size of the image, usually 200-500+ individual keypoint for 1 keypoints.

In python, this is the snippet of the list of keypoints I am trying to pass:

```
# Detect keypoints and compute descriptors
orb = cv2.ORB_create()
keypoints1 = orb.detect(img1, None)
keypoints2 = orb.detect(img2, None)
keypoints1, descriptors1 = orb.compute(img1, keypoints1)
keypoints2, descriptors2 = orb.compute(img2, keypoints2)

# Convert keypoints to Python lists of cv::KeyPoint objects
keypoints1_list = [cv2.KeyPoint(kp.pt[0], kp.pt[1], kp.size, kp.angle, kp.response, kp.octave, kp.class_id) for kp in keypoints1]
keypoints2_list = [cv2.KeyPoint(kp.pt[0], kp.pt[1], kp.size, kp.angle, kp.response, kp.octave, kp.class_id) for kp in keypoints2]

arr_kp1= np.ascontiguousarray(keypoints1_list)
arr_kp2= np.ascontiguousarray(keypoints2_list)

opencvwrapper.evaluateFeatureDetector(arr_img1, arr_img2, arr_kp1, arr_kp2)
```

I am trying to receive it in a C++ script with the OpenCV 3.4.8 library and pybind11 library

```
float evaluateFeatureDetector(py::array_t<uint8_t>& arr1, py::array_t<uint8_t>& arr2, py::array_t<cv::KeyPoint>& keypoints1, py::array_t<cv::KeyPoint>& keypoints2){
... 
cv::Mat H1to2= cv::findHomography(keypoints1, keypoints2, cv::RANSAC);
// Do some more computations here
}
```

However, I keep getting a Type Error like this:

```
TypeError: evaluateFeatureDetector(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: cv::Mat, arg1: cv::Mat, arg2: List[cv::KeyPoint], arg3: List[cv::KeyPoint]) -> float

Invoked with: array([[[ 2,  4,  4],
        [ 1,  3,  3],
        [ 0,  2,  2],
        ...,
        [ 1,  4,  2],
        [ 0,  3,  1]]], dtype=uint8), array([[[12, 12, 12],
        [11, 11, 11],
        [11, 11, 11],
        ...,
        [44, 44, 44],
        [47, 47, 47],
        [47, 47, 47]]], dtype=uint8), [<KeyPoint 0x7f96a7239060>, <KeyPoint 0x7f96a7239090>, <KeyPoint 0x7f96a72390c0>, ...
```

Any tips and advice? Please and thanks.

I tried solving it by:

1. Originally it was `std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>& keypoints1` but I keep getting the same error, I tried using `py::array_t<cv::KeyPoint>& keypoints1` however the typeerror remains.
2. `np.ascontiguousarray()` but the `cv::KeyPoint` is not recognized as a np type.
3. In the C++ side, I tried changing from `cv::KeyPoint` to just float. However, other errors comeout related to  `cv::findHomography()` expecting a input of type `cv::InputArray`

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you would need `c++` code? I don't get the point here.

Comment: I need the C++ code since the OpenCV function `evaluateFeatureDetector` is only available in C++. Hence the C++ code is an OpenCV wrapper.